# Move Old Commit to New Branch

Tags: git, branch

I've accidentally started working on a new feature in the middle of another. My repository simply looks like this:

```
A - B - C - D - E master
```

But I'm hoping to make it look like this:

```
A - B - D - E     master
       \
        C         new-feature
```

It seems like a simple question, but I haven't yet found an answer to it by searching. It seems like cherry-picking is close to what I want, and also maybe some rebasing, but I'm new to Git and some help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, to make the new branch:

```
git branch new-feature C
```

Next, to fix up master

```
git checkout master
git rebase -i B
```

When the editor comes up, delete C from the list.  Save and exit.

Comment: Thanks so much! Been looking for an explanation like this.

Comment: After the rebase, `git push` will refuse to push master because of conflicts with the remote. I've used `git push origin +master` to get it up, but I'm not sure its the correct choice.

Comment: This may not do what’s expected, at least if you transplant multiple past commits—the new branch may end up having duplicates of some commits in the rebased master.

Answer (score 3):

I'll be using some pretty dangerous operations here, so just take note.

This answer makes several assumptions:

1. Your final `master` branch should look like this:
   `A - B - D - E`
2. Your final `new-feature` branch should look like this:
   `A - B - C`
3. Absence of commit `C` will not affect applying commits `D` and `E` on top of commit `B`.

If that's not the case, please update here.

First, on the **master** branch, we create a new branch as a backup. Let's just call it 'backup'.

```
git branch backup
```

This is to allow us to easily restore the master branch in case anything goes wrong later. Of course we could use `git reflog` but this is much more convenient.

Next, on the master branch, do a:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

This should fire up a text editor for `git rebase` (interactive mode). Find the line for commit `C` and remove it.

Now, your master branch should look like:

`A - B - D' - E'`

Dont worry about me writing `A - B - D' - E'` instead of `A - B - D - E`. `D` and `D'` are essentially equivalent in terms of changesets. Same for `E` and `E'`.

We are getting there. I am assuming commit `C` on the `new-feature` branch is to be branched off from commit `B`. Find the commit SHA1 for commit `B`, then (omit the angle brackets below):

`git checkout -b new-feature <SHA1 of commit B>`

This will create a branch called `new-feature` that starts on commit `B`, and checks it out for you. Now we are on `new-feature` branch and it looks like this:

`A - B`

The last step is to find out the commit SHA1 of commit `C`. We have it in the `backup` branch.
Using `git log backup` (or some other method), find the commit SHA1 of commit `C` on the backup branch. After that, on the `new-feature` branch, do:

`git cherry-pick <SHA1 of commit C>`

Of course, please omit the angle brackets.

Now, the `new-feature` branch should look like:

`A - B - C'`

Comment: `C`'s parent is already `B`.  If you just make that branch before rebasing, you don't need to do any gymnastics.

Comment: Wow, appreciate the in-depth code. I think it helps my understanding, if not in practice.

Answer (score 1):

Assume you are currently on the branch `master`

1. `git branch new-feature master~2` Now branch `new-feature` is created and points to the C commit. (You are still working on branch `master` once finished)
2. `git rebase --onto master~3 master~2` This transplants all the commits from `master~2` to the head of `master` onto commit B (i.e., `master~3`).

OK, you are done!

Always use `git help <cmd>` for details.

Comment: Thanks, Frank. I kind of wanted to get rid of the commit, too, though.

Comment: Certainly C is _deleted_ from branch `master` (C is only accessible from branch `new-feature` now). The `git rebase --onto` is the best way for your issue, to my understanding.